# "vertical-align:middle" works as inline style but not in external CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

This has been bugging me a lot and when I try to google anything related to the subject, all I get is Stack Overflow questions about `vertical-align` not working on `div`s or similar elements.

I have this HTML table where as you can see, I set the style of each `td` to `vertical-align:middle` through an HTML inline style attribute:

```
<div ng-hide="getShoppingCart().length===0" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-2"></th>
        <th class="col-md-3">Name</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">Size</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">Price</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">Quantity</th>
        <th class="col-md-1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="article in getShoppingCart()" style="height:120px;">

        <!-- Image -->
        <td class="col-md-2" align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <img ng-src="{{article.media.images[0].smallHdUrl}}" class="img-responsive" style="height:120px;" >
        </td>

        <!-- Name -->
        <td class="col-md-3" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <p>{{ article.name }}</p>
        </td>
        <!-- Size -->
        <td class="col-md-2" style="vertical-align:middle;">
          <p>{{ article.unit.size }}</p>
        </td>

        <!-- Price -->
        <td class="col-md-2" style="vertical-align:middle;">
          <p>£ {{ getTotalPriceForArticle($index) | number : 2 }}</p>
        </td>

        <!-- Quantity -->
        <td class="col-md-2" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <button class="btn minusButtons" ng-click="decrementQuantity(article, $index)">–</button>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" style="position:relative;top:2px;width:4vw;display:inline-block;" ng-model="getQuantities()[$index]"/>
            <button class="btn plusButtons" ng-click="incrementQuantity(article, $index)">+</button>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1" align="left" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <button ng-click="removeArticleAtIndex($index)" class="btn redButtons" style="margin-left:0;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
<div class="col-md-12" style="font-size:2vw; text-align:right;">
    Total Price: £ {{ getTotalPrice() | number : 2 }}
</div>
```

So naturally I thought I could remove all of these inline styles and add this global rule in my external CSS file:

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But when I do that, the contents of the table's cells stop being aligned to the middle. I'm sure that the CSS file is properly linked as other elements are clearly affected by it. Also I checked the rest of the CSS and there are no other rules with higher priority overriding this property for this table. Any ideas?

**Note:** As you can probably figure out from the code, I'm using AngularJS and the table rows are being generated using ng-repeat, in case it could have something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to bootstrap overriding this with a higher specificity.  This is what I see in the chrome developer console for td's:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

I would recommend doing something like the following:

```
.table.td-vertical-center>tbody>tr>td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Then in your table element you can do this:

```
<table class="table table-striped td-vertical-center">
```

This will allow you to wrap this style in a custom class that will not override bootstrap by default, as well as give it enough specificity to update the table cells.

You can see a working example of a bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/bKalP4vU0b)

Comment: You're right! How could I not have suspected bootstrap's CSS to have something to do with it! And obviously your solution works well. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the accepted answer, and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
td, th {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While this worked, I thought I should go with the answer that describes the reason behind the problem and that's more than just "!important everything!".